# Searching CSV file using Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, unix, csv, terminal, grep

I have a 2GB csv file with millions of rows and 15 columns .. something like this,
ID, State, Value 1, Value 2, etc.

I'm trying to search for row(s) that contain multiple matches. For eg., all rows where ID = 123, State = CA and Value 2 = 100.

I've been able to use grep for single value searches ($ grep 'CA' file.csv) but I havent been able to figure out how to use grep for multiple matches.

Can someone help me? I'm not a coder but would like to be able to use Mac Terminal for basic parsing of large CSV files.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably check out [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix).

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of one command to another grep, like so:

```
grep "CA" file.csv | grep 123 | grep 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way which might be slightly faster as it would only scan the file once would be to use awk.

```
awk -F "," '$1 == 100 && $3 eq "banana"' mydata.csv
```

The -F specifies the separator is a comma.
The logic is just $1 for first column $2 for second column etc.
If you are comparing strings use eq
If you are comparing numbers use ==
I have used an example data file called mydata.csv